# How to copy-paste path statements for search results (Win 8)

Tags: windows-8, search, path

Windows 8.1

I want to search my whole disc for folders whose names contain a certain text string.  When I get the results, I want to be able to get a copy-pasteable path statement for each found folder. (Then paste it somewhere else).

The 'details view' in the search results isn't copy-paste-able (and is backwards!), so that's no good.

If I open one of the folders that resulted from the search, its address bar doesn't contain its actual path statement (it has some "searchy" path statement instead), so I can't copy paste the path of the actual folder.

I've got a workaround if the folder contains mp3s (open a mp3 in foobar2000 player, then use that to "open containing folder", and look-up the path from there), but this doesn't work with other filetypes.

How can I do this natively in Windows 8?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-click folders > Copy as path.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW that MP3 > foobar workaround is not needed just to jump to where the search result is located. Just right-click any file/folder in the search results and click *Open file/folder location*.

Comment: again, thanks  :)     My right click menu is so lengthy, I didn't notice that one (two).